# Date Time Column of DataBase not accepting values from excel sheet using SQLBULKCOPY

Tags: c#, excel, sqlbulkcopy

I have a `excel sheet` and it is to be copied to `DataBase`. The excelsheet is having one column as `DateOfBirth`, similarly the table in DataBase also as column `DateOfBirth` which is `DateTime`.
But now when I am copying using `SqlBulkCopy` it is throwing a exception

```
The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type datetime of the specified target column.
```

I have tried various Dates format through the excel sheet, but the error is same.

Comment: I think, there might be empty value in some cell of DateofBirth column of excel sheet....

Comment: There is only 1 row in that sheet and it has a value.I have tried various formats of Dates.

Comment: just use the numerical value representation. And also make sure to use the value2 property of the cell if you can (which i doubt seeing the BULKcopy)

Comment: using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new sqlBulkCopy(con,SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity,Trans1))
                                                {                                        
                                                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = selectedsheet; 
                                                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt.CreateDataReader());
                                                    bulkCopy.Close();                                         
                                                }

Comment: I am converting the excel sheet into DataTable and then pushing the DataTable into DataBase. The DataTable is having all the columns as Object{string}. I think this is the issue.